# How to check oldest comments on a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to use the YouTube data api to get the oldest comments on a certain YouTube video but I don't believe that is possible through the api. Do I have to get every single comment on the video, and then order it to complete this task? Are there any websites that do this already that can help me other than hadzy.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is possible to retrieve the oldest comments on a certain YouTube video using YouTube Data API v3 but AFAIK not with a single query.
2. By default comments are ordered by time with the most recent first, see [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list)
3. I tested [emap.cc](https://emapp.cc/youtube-first-comment) but it doesn't work or is far too slow.

If you are looking for the first comment writer [on MrBeast 100 M subscribers video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2isYuQZMbdU) with his challenge winning 10,000 $ [as announced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZklZVaU4AI). Then as far as I checked, MrBeast pinned for a few minutes that Troy Gaines has won (whose channel should be [this one](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCN1dBTu8w5eSFngwGaaIZHw) according to me with the comment `$$$` published at 20:00:01). However by running the following Python algorithm you can verify that he isn't the first one and that's instead [Marina Marcon](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPXSOxDyVz1dKC4Yu8t33Kw) having commented `Meu` at 19:59:59 (the video was made public at 19:59:59 (use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to check it), **assuming that both of these persons haven't changed their name**):

```py
import json, requests

# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID gives the approximate number of comments we have to retrieve

def curl(url):
    return requests.get(url).text

API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
VIDEO_ID = '2isYuQZMbdU'

nextPageToken = ''
itemsCounter = 0

while True:
    url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={VIDEO_ID}&key={API_KEY}&maxResults=100'
    if nextPageToken != '':
        url += f'&pageToken={nextPageToken}'
    responseStr = curl(url)
    try:
        responseJSON = json.loads(responseStr)
    except:
        print(url, responseStr)
    items = responseJSON['items']
    for item in items:
        if 'Troy Gaines' == item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName']:
            print(item)
    ids = [item['id'] for item in items]
    itemsCounter += len(items)
    print(nextPageToken, itemsCounter, len(items))
    if 'nextPageToken' in responseJSON and nextPageToken != responseJSON['nextPageToken']:
        nextPageToken = responseJSON['nextPageToken']
    else:
        print(url, items[-1])
        break
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how it's possible for someone to comment at 19:59:59 (the second the video was uploaded). I created a bot that spam requested the API 20 times per second to see if he had uploaded and if he did the script sent another api request to post a comment. The response JSON said my comment was posted at  20:00:01 which is the same time Troy did. I guess it was a matter of luck.

Comment: I think being near a YouTube node, using a low-level programming language such as Rust, using various instances, using various endpoints such as Search: list, CommentThreads: list, PlaylistItems: list... YT Data API v3 and some YT UI endpoints and maybe using a zero day (allowing to know the video id before the publication date, likewise you can just spam CommentThreads: insert and it will insert successfully your comment on time as you can't comment private video, that is the state of it before the publication date).

Comment: As you said it's a bit of luck in the end and I find it too bad that it's not more transparent how they picked the winner (sharing the channel id and not name because everybody rename themself to the winner name), keep public who won (not just pinning a comment for a few seconds), considering the real first person (which wasn't the case, having a ms precision with CommentThreads: list would be useful here) and I'm even unsure that the winner will receive its reward as there isn't any contact on his YT channel (if my answer assumption holds).

Comment: And being able with a single API call to CommentThreads: list to retrieve the first comment shouldn't be missing.